# CFUNCTYPE causes segmentation fault

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I have a simple C code which takes some number and returns a string.

```c
const char * get_err_string(const uint8_t errcode) {

    switch (errcode) {
        case 0:
            return "No errors";
            break;
        case 1:
            return "Some error";
            break;
        default:
            return "There is no such error code";
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to execute it with `ctypes` using a function prototype, but I get segmentation fault every time.

```py
import ctypes

libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("lib.so")

get_err_string = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(
    ctypes.c_char_p,  # restype
    ctypes.c_uint8  # 1st argument
)(libc.get_err_string)

get_err_string(ctypes.c_uint8(0))  # segmentation fault
```

What did surprised me, is that a slightly different code executes just ok.

```py
import ctypes

libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("genevo/c/bin/genevo.so")

get_err_string = libc.get_err_string
get_err_string.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
get_err_string.argtypes = [ctypes.c_uint8]

get_err_string(ctypes.c_uint8(0))  # b'No errors.'
```

So, why is that? Is there something I miss?

Comment: Semicolon after ```return "No errors"``` is missing.

Comment: @MarsZ'uh yes, my bad. I was trying to give minimal working example and forgotten it.

Comment: guess it's a thing for gdb to inspect. set a ```b get_err_string``` in both scenarios, and compare the regs, esp. %rdi %rsi and %rax as those might differ in both calls. See the x86_64 ABI (wildly assuming you're running the most common arch), e.g. on p22 here: https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/x86_64-abi-0.99.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CFUNCTYPE` is not being called with correct parameters.  See [Function Prototypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#function-prototypes) in the [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) documentation (excerpt):

> Function prototypes created by these factory functions can be
> instantiated in different ways, depending on the type and number of
> the parameters in the call:
>
> **prototype**(*address*)
> Returns a foreign function at the specified address
> which must be an integer.
>
> **prototype**(*callable*)
> Create a C callable function (a callback function)
> from a Python callable.
>
> **prototype**(*func_spec*[*, paramflags*])
> Returns a foreign function exported
> by a shared library. func_spec must be a 2-tuple (name_or_ordinal,
> library). The first item is the name of the exported function as
> string, or the ordinal of the exported function as small integer. The
> second item is the shared library instance.

Use the 3rd version above in this case:

```py
import ctypes as ct

libc = ct.CDLL('./test')
prototype = ct.CFUNCTYPE(ct.c_char_p, ct.c_uint8)
get_err_string = prototype(('get_err_string',libc))
print(get_err_string(0))
```

```c
// Complete test.c for reference (Windows DLL)
#include <stdint.h>

__declspec(dllexport)
const char * get_err_string(const uint8_t errcode) {
    switch (errcode) {
        case 0:
            return "No errors";
            break;
        case 1:
            return "Some error";
            break;
        default:
            return "There is no such error code";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
b'No errors'
```

Note that doing it your 2nd way is the *usual* way to call a function:

```py
import ctypes as ct

libc = ct.CDLL('./test')
libc.get_err_string.argtypes = ct.c_uint8,
libc.get_err_string.restype = ct.c_char_p

print(libc.get_err_string(0))
```

Output:

```
b'No errors'
```

But there are some advantages to the first way, namely specifying which parameters are input/output, and assigning parameter names and defaults to make it more "Pythonic".

Comment: Okay, it works, thanks. Although, I can't understand why passing `libc.get_err_string` into prototype is wrong. `get_err_string` is also Python callable.

Comment: @PaulLynn Yes, but the 2nd usage makes a Python function callable by C so you can pass a Python function to C as a callback, which isn't what you are doing.  The 3rd usage returns a foreign function (C callable) that is callable by Python.  You can kind of make the 2nd usage work by assigning `.argtypes` and `.restype` to `libc.get_err_string` before passing it to `CFUNCTYPE`.  I got it to work but got a memory leak warning from ctypes when trying it.  It's the wrong way to do it.